# MySQL Group By and return distinct rows from grouped result based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Background**

1. The table below shows the list of products across the three branches of a particular Phone Shop
2. "branch_id" with value "0" means the product is available in all branches
3. I would like to query for distinct products whose "branch_id = 2" - including those in a comma-separated string AND "branch_id = 0";
4. However, if the result returns more than one row with the same "product_name", in this case "Iphone X", the row with the "branch_id" not equal to "0" should be returned.

**Products**

| id | product_name | branch_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Iphone X | 2,3 | 700 |
| 2 | Iphone X | 0 | 500 |
| 3 | Samsung S8 | 2 | 600 |
| 4 | Ipad Pro | 1 | 750 |
| 5 | Apple watch | 0 | 550 |
| 6 | Samsung S9 | 1,2 | 600 |

**Expected Result**

| id | product_name | branch_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Iphone X | 2 | 700 |
| 3 | Samsung S8 | 2 | 600 |
| 5 | Apple watch | 0 | 550 |
| 6 | Samsung S9 | 2 | 600 |

**My Query** - it doesn't return rows with branch_id = 0

```
    select  id, product_name, branch_id, price FROM products 
    group by product_name,branch_id 
    having CASE 
       WHEN FIND_IN_SET(2, branch_id) > 0 THEN FIND_IN_SET(2, branch_id) > 0
       WHEN branch_id = 0 THEN branch_id = 0
       ELSE  branch_id = NULL 
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id, product_name, 
       CASE WHEN branch_id = '0' THEN branch_id ELSE '2' END branch_id, 
       price
FROM Products p1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, p1.branch_id)
   OR (
     p1.branch_id = 0 
     AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM Products p2
       WHERE p2.product_name = p1.product_name
         AND FIND_IN_SET(2, p2.branch_id)
     )
   );
```

Or, if your version of MySql is 8.0+ use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT id, product_name, 
       CASE WHEN branch_id = '0' THEN branch_id ELSE '2' END branch_id, 
       price
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_name ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(2, branch_id) > 0 DESC) rn
  FROM Products
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, branch_id) OR branch_id = '0'
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3077d18fb6eebfccb9f022cc00276708).